# iQueryable LINQ lambda OrderByDescending() is slower than OrderBy()

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I am doing the sorting and paging related task on the `IQueryable<T>` object.

I am using the following code for the dynamic sorting:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, bool asc)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    string methodName = asc ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    var orderByExp1 = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                      new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
                      source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

When I passed the below information for Ascending sorting than it takes `4 Sec`.

```
Num = 1000;
StartIndex = 1;
SortKey = "ID";
SortOrder = true; // OrderBy
```

I successfully get the `1000` records in Ascending order only in the `4 Sec`.

But When I want the records in the Descending order than it takes `41 Sec` for the `1000` records.

```
Num = 1000;
StartIndex = 1;
SortKey = "ID";
SortOrder = false; // OrderByDescending
```

Ascending Order => 4 Sec.

Descending Order => 41 Sec.

So my question is that `OrderByDescending` is slower than `OrderBy` ?

Comment: What are the indexes on the table?

Comment: And relatedly, how do the corresponding sql queries perform?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten `ID` is only index which is AUTO INCREMENT. In my table I have the 5,00,000 records.

Comment: So.. you've got your answer right there. `ID` is a clustered index - change it to be descending

Comment: @JonHanna, I take the query from the from the MSSQL profiler for ascending and descending. I execute the SQL ascending query in the SQL manager it takes 1 sec and descending query takes the 20 sec.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Thank you, I don't know but may be you right. Let me check this.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten, If I made that changes than Ascending order will take the 41 sec and descending order will take 4 sec ?

Comment: I would believe so. Is It SqlServer? Can you show the execution plan for both cases?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Yes it is the Microsoft SQL Server.